# filter metadata with opensearch_vector_search

Tags: vector, langchain, opensearch

Hi i am trying to run similarity search on my vector DB , in my db i added some document along with metadata like below

`docs = [Document(page_content='The Structure of the Sun to the center.', metadata={'source': '/tmp/tmp3doww_i3/tmp.pdf', 'page': 1}), Document(page_content='\uf0b7 Radiation pressure : it is Credit: NASA', metadata={'source': '/tmp/tmp3doww_i3/tmp.pdf', 'page': 1}), Document(page_content='The Structu regions', metadata={'source': '/tmp/tmp3doww_i3/tmp.pdf', 'page': 2}))]`

now i want to run the pre filter on page = 1 and the run similarity

`filter = {"bool": {"filter": {"term": {"page": 6}}}} resdocs = opensearch_vector_search.similarity_search(" heterogenous individual growth",filter) resdocs`

I am trying to ask related to vector db similarity with filters and i expected the best answers from community

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in order to use metadata filtering you must access the field in metadata dictionary (like *metadata.page*) and then access the keyword version of the field (like *metadata.page.keyword*). After this your filter should work has intended.
The filter becomes: {"bool": {"filter": {"term": {"metadata.page.keyword": 6}}}}